# How to allow ajax form submit on each click?

Tags: ajax

I noticed that my ajax form can submit twice at the most, meaning once I submit and retrieve data and want to submit the form again to refine search(it's a search form) it can do it. More than twice it cannot submit, the submit button also becomes disabled. Is there any restriction on ajax form to get submitted multiple times?

My form submission is trigered by

```
$("form").on("submit", function () ...
```

ajax:

```
var getData;

$("form").on("submit", function () {
    //$(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    var data = {
        "action": "test"
    };

    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "ajax2.php",
        data: data,

        success: function (data) {

            getData=data;
            //$("#main_content").slideUp("normal",function(){   
            $(".the-return").show();



           if(data!=""){
               console.log(data.length);
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                //availability
            if(data[i].weekM==0)
            {
                var avail="Not available";
            }
            else
            {
                avail="Available";
            }

            if(data[i].endA==0)
            {
                var avail2="Not available";
            }
            else
            {
                avail2="Available";
            }

            if(data[i].weekE==0)
            {
                var avail3="Not available";
            }
            else
            {
                avail3="Available";
            }



$(".the-inner-return").append("<div class='inside_return'><section class='row'><div class='small-10 medium-10 large-8 small-centered medium-centered large-centered columns d_result'><div class='text-center post_id'>" + data[i].id +"</div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-9 columns subject'>"+ data[i].subject+" Instructor</div><div class='small-12 meidum-12 large-3 columns rate'>" + data[i].rate +"</div><span class='hourly'>hourly</span><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 text-center name'>" + data[i].name +"</div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-4 columns plusneg'><img src='img/happy.png'>" + data[i].plus+"<br/><img src='img/sad.png'>"+ data[i].neg+"</div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-4 columns gender text-center'>Male<br/>Availabiliy:<br/>Mornings:<span class='avail'>" + avail+"</span><br/>Afternoons:<br/><span class='avail'>"+ avail2+"</span><br/>Evening:<span class='avail'>"+ avail3+"</span></div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-4 columns score text-center'><h6>Reputation score</h6>"+ data[i].reputation+"</div><div class='row'><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-5 columns shortlist text-center'>Add to Shorlist</div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-5 columns gettutor text-center'>Get Tutor</div></div><div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-center date'>Posted on:<span class='elec'>"+ data[i].postDate+"</span></div></div></section></div>");

            //alert(data[i].name) 
            }
           }else{
               $(".the-return").hide();
               $("#the-return-fail").show();
           }

            //});//closes #main_content
        }


    });
    return false;


});
```

Comment: This is a bit vague, could you add your ajax call and the HTML? most helpfully in a jsfiddle. AFAIK, there is no limits on submitting via AJAX unless you put the code in yourself.

Comment: @Daemedeor, added the ajax code

Comment: @Daemedeor, heres the fiddle with complete html and ajax..http://jsfiddle.net/w8bs04j8/

Comment: You need to prevent the default browser submission... `.on("submit", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); ... }` because you are submitting with an AJAX request. I see you return false, but if you have script errors that won't get there.

Comment: @Jasen, can I use click in the place of event above?

Comment: I would use the click event instead but be sure to remove the `type="submit"` from the button.

Comment: @Jasen, not working though

Comment: With `$(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled','disabled');` are you attempting to disable the submit button? When do you re-enable it?

Comment: @Jasen, nope I commented out the $(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled','disabled');

Comment: There's a few errors in your code to begin with, you should declare your vars at the top because like var avail3 won't be declared in the if-else. (if it was true, it'll get declared but in the second one it isn't declared). you don't need to return false since you're not really doing anything and possibly instead of submit use the click functionality on a div or something. (going through the fiddle one moment)

Comment: There is no counter that prevents multiple ajax submissions. However, if you are attempting to submit before the previous request is complete then you probably are going to have problems if you use global variables. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/bnr5odk8/) that does multiple submissions. You can comment out the button disable lines to see what happens.

Comment: @Daemedeor, okay will be waiting for r feedback..thanks

Comment: @sherly I couldn't find anything that would explicitly set the button to disabled but I did some updates that could potentially help your code, I think the cause is likely the var avail(s) being called where they are, they should be set outside the if tests because you're not declaring them otherwise: http://jsfiddle.net/w8bs04j8/2/

Comment: @Daemedeor, I found that event handlers were causing the issue. Once removed, can submit many times now

Answer (score 0):

There is no counter that prevents multiple ajax submissions. However, if you are attempting to submit before the previous request is complete then you probably are going to have problems if you use global variables.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/bnr5odk8/) that does multiple submissions.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="foo" id="foo" type="text" />
    <button>Send It</button>
</form>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

The `data` here is formatted for JSFiddle's echo service

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // prevent next submission before request is complete
    $("button").prop("disabled", true);

    var dt = new Date();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        method: "post",
        data: {
            json: JSON.stringify({
                date: new Date(),
                foo: $("#foo").val()
            }),
            delay: 3
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#output").append($("<div>").html(result.foo + " " + result.date));
            $("button").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```